# Not to give a divorce (Get) in the month of Iyar

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, divorce, months

I heard today in Shul that there is a Minhag not to give a divorce in the month of Iyar. What is the source and reason for this Minhag?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rama writes, when discussing how to spell the various Hebrew months in a Get (Shulchan Aruch EH 126:7):

> אייר, בשני יודי"ן; ואם כתב בחד יו"ד, פסול, אם לא בשעת הדחק. ויש נמנעין ליתן גט באייר, אך במקום הדחק נותנין וכותבין בב' יודי"ן.‏
>   Iyar is spelled with two Yuds. If one wrote it with one Yud, it is invalid except in pressing circumstances. Some refrain from giving a Get in Iyar [because of the doubt], but if forced to they will give a Get and spell [Iyar] with two Yuds.

The Aruch haShulchan ([bio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein)) notes (EH 126:15) the common practice near him was not to refrain from divorcing in the month of Iyar. I'm told that the [Beth Din of America](http://www.bethdin.org/jewish-divorce.asp) does arrange for divorces in the month of Iyar. I'll also note that the Mechaber (EH 126:23) rules unambiguously that Iyar is spelled with two Yuds, so there doesn't seem to be much room to be stringent in this matter for Sefardim.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance -- is Ramah saying "don't give a Get in Iyar" to avoid the dispute of how to spell it, or out of concern that people won't properly spell it with two yuds?

Comment: @Shalom No, pardon _my_ ignorance! I didn't even think of that. Let me check the Darkei Moshe now.

Comment: @Shalom This is the DM after citing that Iyar is spelled with 2 Yuds: ומצאתי כתוב בשם מהר"י מולין דפסק ליתן ב' גיטין באייר מכח ספק ויש נמנעין ליתן גט באייר מכח ספק. I think that supports my read. Thank you for making me check!

Answer (score 2):

To add to what has already been said, I once heard a deeper reason behind the psak of not giving a get in Iyar. One of the themes of Iyar is "Second Chances" - such as -

**Pesach Sheini** second chance for korban Pesach

**Lag BaOmer** second chance for Torah, it was on that day Rabbi Akiva decided after all his talmidim died, to start again with five new students

**Healing** Iyar is an auspicious time for healing, as the acronym *Ani Hashem Rofecha* suggests. Since a disease (chas veshalom) can be viewed (albeit simplistically) as Hashem urging us to do teshuva, and return to our true path; healing can therefore be seen as a second chance to do what we were meant to do the first time around

It could also be noted- Yom HaAtzmaut, and Yom Yerushalayim fall in Iyar (not hard to think how this fits the theme…)

Therefore, the idea is, since this month is all about "Second Chances" - *how could one give a get in Iyar?*

Comment: <Therefore, the idea is, since this month is all about "Second Chances" - how could one give a get in Iyar?> Adderabba. NOT giving the get is PREVENTING said second chance [for both parties], particularly when it's clear that the first one failed. And if a certain party is using this to withhold [or, maybe, to not take the get]--then said withholder is not only preventing their counterpart from getting on with the post-get life and the second chance it provides, but showing that there is a lack of aziva and kabalah al ha-asid. If second chances mean anything, and Iyar is about second chances,