# Acronym of Iyar

Tags: sources-mekorot, acronyms, months

I read the following on page 141, in [*The Wisdom In The Hebrew Months*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422608982.html):

The first letters of the last three words of this [verse](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.15.26?lang=en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all), אני י-ה-ו-ה רפאך, *I am Hashem, your Healer,* are an acronym for *Iyar*.

Is any source that says that אייר stands for אני י-ה-ו-ה רפאך?

Comment: Actually Iyar is spelled with two Yuds. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28460/759

Comment: I wouldnt put too much faith in it considering that the names of the hebrew months are borrowed from non-Jewish Babylonian sources. Then again, that didnt stop the Tur from expounding the roshei teivit of "Elul".

Comment: "Is any source": you mean, besides _The Wisdom In The Hebrew Months_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Chasam Sofer on Shabbos 147b, http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21655&st=&pgnum=80.

That the names of the months come from the Babylonians, so what? The name Amraphel comes from Babylonian or some similar language, but it is darshened as having a Hebrew meaning. Same with Sancheriv and lots of other examples.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Shamiach! thank you for your answer. Consider learning more about this website by taking this brief tour: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour. For general help see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help. For info. about answering questions see for example here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Hope to see you around the site.

Comment: What was your intent with the Chassam Sofer, I don't see how it addressed the question. Your whole answer should perhaps be a comment rather than an answer as the the question was specifically looking for a source for the drasha about iyar (which I didnt see in the link, forgive me if it was there).

Comment: @mevaqesh: Chiddushei Torah asked for a source; it's been provided. How does that not answer the question?

Comment: @Shamiach I guess I didnt see it in 147b. All I saw was the general drasha of choshei hashana. It could be I just missed it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Chasam Sofer [already quoted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57449/440), another source is the [Shaar Yisachar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4765&st=&pgnum=96&hilite=) in the name of "holy seforim", who addresses kabbalistically why the acronym holds despite the halacha that Iyar is written with two yuds.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe explains the concept at length [here](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/lkus/32/7/1).

Answer (score -3):

Building on what mevaqesh said. The names are borrowed directly from the pagan Babylonians. Some of them are actually names of foreign gods. Like the month of Tammuz, mentioned in [Ezekiel 8:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1208.htm). I don't know if Iyyar happens to be a name of a foreign god, but maybe you could look into that. But I can guarantee you that when the Babylonians decided on naming the month Iyyar, there was zero possibility that it had anything to do with the tetragrammaton, or the Israelite people. Therefore, I doubt there's any reliable source that says that Iyaar stands for a phrase from the Pentateuch containing the tetragrammaton.

If you would like to know what the Bible called the month of Iyyar, it's called  זו as is mentioned in [1 Kings 6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a06.htm). Maybe you can write the author of The Wisdom in the Hebrew Months and ask him what significance זו has.

Comment: While true, this doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Ah, maybe i'm ignorant for how this board works. So if we know something is false, regardless of the question, proving falsehood isn't the point, the point is that we are supposed to only focus on answering the question?

Comment: What exactly have you proven false that is relevant to the question? In general, answering what was asked is a good strategy.

Comment: @DoubleAA Good now?

Comment: @msh210 It answers the question now, but I don't think it's what the author intended. I think he intended to claim that whether or not there is some source, any such word-association is meaningless/post-facto.

Comment: Re "If you would like to know what the Bible called the month of Iyyar": note that our (Babylonian) names for the months do appear in the Bible (though _Iyar_ doesn't, I don't think).

Comment: @DoubleAA, you may well be right. But note that I included the word "reliable". Aaron, please check whether my edit matches your intent.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah i'm sorry i did a very poor job.