# Spelling mismatch between ketubah and gett

Tags: divorce, ketubah, maseches-gitin, mamzer

Without going into the whole Gantsah Geshichta, my sister is trying to convince me of the critical importance of the spelling of a person's name. She points to a local Rabbi who is an "expert in the spelling of names". She says that he's often consulted when a ketubah or a gett is written.

Okay, I understand the importance, and I can see him being consulted for a ketubah. But a gett?? What if someone's name is written one way on the ketubah and then it's decided that there's a "more correct" way to spell it and this spelling is used on the gett thereby creating a mismatch between these documents.

In a case like this, does the gett really do what its supposed to? Is this simply an open invitation to create mamzerim?

Comment: are you asking about the underlying importance of accurate spellings (there are books on the matter) or about the hypothetical halachic consequence of a mismatch between name spellings on the 2 documents?

Comment: @rosends No, the importance of spelling is not at issue here. What is the issue is if the ketubah and gett have different names (or differnt spellings of names) on them is the gett really valid to dissolve that marriage. I could see someone seeing the mismatch and suggesting that the couple is really not halachicly divorced which would open up the possiblity of mamzer if the woman remarries and has a child.

Comment: Here is a question about an Ashkenazi minhag not to give a get during the month of Iyar because the Rema says there is a debate about whether the name of the month is spelled with one or two yuds and therefore the get may be invalid. Kal v'homer the name of the husband or wife! https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28459/not-to-give-a-divorce-get-in-the-month-of-iyar

Comment: @יהושעק This is interesting, but what exactly is the Kal v'homer? Let's say the bride's name is misspelled on the ketubah. Things don't work out and the guy wants to give a gett. Suddenly, someone notices the mistake and when the gett is written, the correct spelling is used. What happens? (1) Since the gett is referencing a de facto non-existant marriage, there is no legal divorce. OR (2) The gett is viewed as completely legit since everything is spelled correctly and the divorce is legal.

Comment: In a Kesubah we only write one name, in the get that write every possible name that the person may of ever been called. Presumably, they would write the correct spelling and then add the wrong spelling as an additional name

Comment: @Chatzkel  Huh??!! I never knew that. I do see a reference to this on the Chabad website which states "Just to be absolutely clear about the identities of the parties, any nicknames by which the husband or wife are known are also included in the document."

Comment: The Kal v'homer is, if the get can be invalidated on the basis of the spelling of the name of the month, all the more so if it involves the name of the husband or wife. In practice, the method @Chatkel discusses is what's used anyway

Comment: @SanderSmith it’s done by every get.

Comment: I think what youre missing is a marriage is valid even if the ketubba (the document outlining their obligations to each other) is invalid for some reason. The ring-giving effects the marriage, not the ketubba. If a get is invalid then the divorce fails entirely and they are still married.

Comment: https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/transliterating-english-names-for-ketubot-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

Comment: I know someone who on the invitation it was spelled one way, the ketubba a different way and on the get a third way

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, a discrepancy in spelling isn't a problem; it's having the wrong name in a Gett that's a problem.

There are some names where the halacha says "multiple spellings are acceptable, so follow what you commonly use"; but there are others where the halacha is: "there is one right way to do it."

Pinchas is a case of the latter; the proper way is always with a Yud. Even if he normally writes it without a yud, and if he wrote it without a Yud in the Kesubah. When it comes to the Gett, they spell it the "right" way. (There is a whole lot more wiggle room with spellings in a Kesubah than a Gett!) If someone compared the documents they would say -- *ah, the kesubah was done by a run-of-the-mill pulpit rabbi, while the Gett was done consulting an expert.* No problem.

The only scenario that could cause headaches is if the kesubah says "Pinchas" and the Gett says "Moshe." (Not "Moshe also known as Pinchas" or anything like that. Just "Moshe.") Then -- you need to talk to a serious posek ...